# Использование svg в опере 12 версии и ниже

Tags: opera, svg, css

Проблема с повтором `svg` фона (выставленного в `css`) в не действует no-repeat браузере Опера 12 и ниже? Проблема, кажется, называется `CORE-33071`. Может кто знает как её можно решить ?

Вот код (немного изменил у меня `wordpress`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" /> 
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats please -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

    <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link'); ?>
    <?php //comments_popup_script(); // off by default ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style/ie.css" type="text/css"/>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header><?php get_header()?>

        <div id="menu-pages">
            <div id="inner_menu_pages">
            <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Меню')) : ?>
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>
            <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
        <div id="content_pages">
                <div id="post_pages">   
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4> 
                    <?php the_content();?> 
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <div class="nav">
                        <?php previous_post_link('%link &nbsp; &nbsp;');?>
                        <?php next_post_link('%link');?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
               </div>
    <?php get_sidebar()?>

    <?php get_footer()?>
```

футер и сайбар я думаю выкладывать ненадо теперь css

```
#news {
    background: url("images/post.svg");
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 572px;
    padding: 57px 0 80px 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -309px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sergalas, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас тредактирую
